# Is there an equivalent to $this for static classes? ( kind of super but for the current class where it is used )

Tags: php, class, static, reference, this

I know it wouldn't be exactly equivalent to $this, but is there a way to reference a static class from within itself without using the name of the class itself?  ( like super but for itself )
This is just a way to avoid having to refactor all the class references if the class is renamed.

Example:

```
class foo {
    function bar() {
        static_this::method();
        // instead of:
        foo::method();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
self::method();
```